# How to find out when a program was started and then closed via cmd batch file and then create a rem on program close

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to keep this simple. I have a ACCESS DB batch file that I want to run from a trusted users computer, or via task scheduler. Batchrun.mdb runs its queries and then exits automatically. I'd like to know how we can tell when it actually closes -- if and when it does i'd like to add a rem line that says update complete or similar with the time.  Thank you! I cannot find anything on this via google. The key is knowing that the program actually opened, and closed. I will remove the exit /b if i can get this to work correctly.

Batch file:

```
Start "" "E:\REDACTED\Batch Files\Batchrun.mdb"

Exit /b
```

Comment: Selfmodifying code, insert between start and exit lines `Echo Rem [%date% %time%] update complete>>"%~f0"`

Comment: Don't use `start`. `Start` says **don't wait for program to exit**. See `start /?`.

Comment: I would expect the *Access* executable to run by association and open the database connection to the mdb file. Try `start "" /wait ...`. Task Scheduler keeps a history for the task which includes the exit code.

Comment: .@ECHO OFF
.@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

Start "" /wait "E:\Cassone\Batch Files\Batchrun.mdb"
echo %date%, %time% Started Batch File >> log.txt

:ProcessLoop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Batchrun.mdb" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Batchrun.mdb">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (GOTO :ProcessLoop) ELSE (GOTO :Closed)

:Closed
echo %date%, %time% COMPLETED Batch File>> log.txt

pause

Exit /b 

Doing this caused cmd to say that the process is already running when it obviously is not. sorry, i havent figured out formatting here yet.

Answer (score 1):

For adding the `REM` within your code, you can do `Echo Rem [%date% %time%] update complete>>"%~f0"` - As posted by @LotPings - And can have the batch loop using `tasklist` to seach for your program. Upon terminating, it will end the loop and print the `REM` timestamp in your script and exit.

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

Start "" "E:\REDACTED\Batch Files\Batchrun.mdb"
Echo Rem [%date% %time%] Application Opened>>"%~f0"

:ProcessLoop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Batchrun.mdb" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Batchrun.mdb">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (GOTO :ProcessLoop) ELSE (GOTO :Closed)

:Closed
Echo Rem [%date% %time%] Application Closed>>"%~f0"
Exit /b

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: LOG
```

Comment: As the IMAGENAME most likely is `MSACCESS.EXE` the loop would never trigger. With `tasklist /V /FO CSV /FI "IMAGENAME eq MSACCESS.EXE"` the mdb name is possibly in Field9 windowtitle.

Comment: ya im running into that issue right now. i dont even know why im doing a batch, i should be doing it a dozen other ways. but thats what they want...  thank you.